# Recursive rosmake --mark-installed

Tags: rosmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While using "rosmake -i" for a package that depends on a couple of other packages, I realized that the "-i" flag, which creates ROS_NOBUILD file, operates only on the current package and not its dependencies. I think it is desirable to either modify behavior of "--mark-installed" option to mark the package and its dependencies as "installed" or introduce a new option, say "--mark-installed-recursive", that will do the job. Any comments are appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12255/recursive-rosmake---mark-installed/) by [Aditya](https://answers.ros.org/users/1106/aditya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 287 on 2011-12-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've opened a ticket for that feature.  https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/3784

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-12-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2